remove class to child element with jquery
I´m trying to do a logic, that when user focus in text div, show a action button to mark as read a message. To do this.
First i´m getting all messages in my view, and i add a block with button:
<div class="row flex-row align-items-center block_message_{{$message->id}}">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @if ($message->publisher_comments != "" || $message->publisher_comments != null)
            <span>{{ $message->publisher_comments }}</span>
        @else
            <span>{{ $message->client_comments }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 d-none" id="block_mark_read_{{$message->id}}">
        <button class="read-more-info-icon modal-right">
            <i class="fa fa-eye fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="hidden-info">{{ trans('placeholders.mark_read') }}</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

And with jquery, i´m trying to use focus event in my parent div, to show icon in my child div, but my icon not show it. and i don´t getting any message or error.
<script>
    let index = 0;
    $(".block_message div").focus(function(event) {
        $(this).removeClass('d-none');
    });
    let block_messages = $(".block_message").map(function() {
        index++;

        let block = $('.block_message_'+index).find('#block_mark_read_'+index);
        

        /*$(this).find("#block_mark_read_"+index).addEventListener('focus', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('d-none');
        })*/

        block.addEventListener('focus', function(){
            console.log("entro");
        })

    })
    
</script>

My question it´s, how i can to do, to show icon beside my div and add action to mark read
EDIT
i´m trying to do with responses:
this.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            /*let block = $(this).children('div')[1];
            $(this).children('div').removeClass('d-none');*/
            console.log($(this).closest("block_message").attr('data-message_id'))
        })

this return undefined
Thanks for reading, help and sorry for my bad english.

You're mixing jquery and vanilla javascript.  It's important to know if you have a jquery object or (eg) a DOM node.   On this line block.addEventListener, block is a jquery object so will be giving you an error (check the browser console).  You could do block[0].addEventListener or you could stick with jquery and do block.on("focus", function()....

You also don't need the incrementing IDs, add a class to all the buttons and use jquery to add event to all, eg $(".block_mark_read").on("click", ... then use this inside the callback and DOM navigation to find which one it applies to, eg $(this).closest("block_message").data("message-id")

@fdomn-m thanks for your responses, but return me undefined with $(this).closest("block_message").data("message-id") 

It's a suggestion... hence the "eg" - you still have to add the data-message-id attribute to the .block_message div

And $(this).closest("block_message") needs to be $(this).closest(".block_message") - otherwise, you would be trying to find an element with the tag name block_message.
